# When does mongodb update the index after a write operation is fired?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I want to know when does an index gets updated after write operation(insert/update/remove) is fired. Is it updated after the db-file on disk is updated or before that?

My understanding is that when JOURNALED write concern is used, the data is written to journal file (after ~33 ms) and then the ack is be sent to client. How does indexes add overhead to write operations here? When are they updated in this scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The write includes all of the parts - modifying the data and modifying all the indexes.

The journal keeps track of "commit groups" so that it is able to replay operations completely and consistently.  If your client received acknowledgement of a write, it means that all of the parts of that write, data and index (and oplog in the case of a replica node) have been completed.

For this reason, your write speed will be affected by the number of indexes that have to be updated when the document is written: the more indexes, the longer each write will take, in that way, MongoDB is quite similar to traditional RDBMSs.